# Modify data in children component and make it available in the parent as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to modify some state parameters inside a child component and then pass it for use in the parent.

I have a state object called driver. Inside of my EditDriver component, I am calling ProfileTab and passing it the driver object, with fields like firstName, and more. Inside of the ProfileTab is where I do the actual modification. Inside the parent component EditDriver is where I need to send this data to the server in the updateDriver function.

```
//...imports
class EditDriver extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        driver: {
            firstName: '',
        },
    };
this.updateDriver = this.updateDriver.bind(this);
this.driverOnChange = this.driverOnChange.bind(this);
}

updateDriver() {
                this.props.updateDriver(this.state.driver);
    }


driverOnChange(data) {
    this.setState({
        driver: data
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <ViewContainer
            fullWidth
            title="Driver"
            toolbarRight={
                <Button
                    onClick={this.updateDriver}
                >
                    Save
                </Button>
            }
        >
            <ProfileTab match={this.props.match} driver={this.state.driver} driverOnChange={this.driverOnChange} />}

        </ViewContainer>
    );
}
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    updateDriver: driver => dispatch(updateDriver(driver))
});

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(withStyles(styles)(EditDriver));
```

and the ProfileTab code looks like this:

```
class ProfileTab extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        driver: {
            firstName: '',
        },
        };

    this.handleDriverInputChange = this.handleDriverInputChange.bind(this);
    }


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.driver && !nextProps.isFetching) {

        this.setState({
            driver: {
                ...this.state.driver,
                ...nextProps.driver
            }
        });
    }
}

handleDriverInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type == 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        driver: {
            ...this.state.driver,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}


render() {
    const {
        driver,
    } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
                    <TextField
                        name="firstName"
                        label="firstName"
                        margin="normal"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.handleDriverInputChange}
                        value={driver.firstName}
                    />
        </div>
    );
}
}


ProfileTab.propTypes = {
driver: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
driverOnChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default ProfileTab;
```

The driverOnChange function does not actually set the state of the driver parameter in the ProfileTab. What would be the most efficient way to render the ProfileTab in the EditDriver component and have the changed parameter firstName available?

Comment: so EditDriver is the parent component and profiletab is child, so the driver details api is called on EditDriver Component and once you get the data you are passsing it to the profiletab component and you render it. Once you change there you need to update the state in the parent component which is EditDriver Component and call the api

Answer (score 0):

Just call driverOnChange in this method inside ProfileTab component

```
handleDriverInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type == 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.props.driverOnChange(value);

    this.setState({
        driver: {
            ...this.state.driver,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}
```

You've binded driverOnChange to EditDriver component therefore I think `this` in driverOnChange would refer to it even when it is being called inside ProfileTab component

Comment: @ksenia i hope that I understood your question correctly, if not then tell me and i'll delete this answer

Comment: thank you, the error I get is in the EditDriver component onDriverChnage function, says 'this.setState is not a function'. do you know what the error could be about?